# Executar Ajax passando informação de credencial no Header

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

Preciso fazer uma chamada ajax passando no Header a seguinte informação:
Content-Type:application/json
Cookie:authToken=valorXPTO
(Essa informação acima eu peguei do Postman)
[image: Exemplo no postam funcionando]

Preciso fazer a mesma coisa só que via Ajax, e de jeito nenhum estou conseguindo. Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Segue o código abaixo:

```
            function LogoutToken(){
        debugger;
            var urlApi = urlBase + "logout";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                url: urlApi,
                crossDomain: true,
                async: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Cookie', 'authToken=' + Token);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    alert('Falha na consulta de valores específicos, erro:' + textStatus);
                },
                success: function (msg) {
                    var xyx = msg;
                }
            });
        }
```

Quando executo dessa forma da o seguinte erro: Internal Server Error

No C# eu executo da seguinte maneira e da certo:

```
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddCookie("authToken", token);
```

Comment: Qual erro que apresenta? Por ser um POST acho que faltou o 'data' (conteudo da requisição).

Comment: @AndersonSouza ele da **Internal Server Error**. Mas eu não tenho dados para passar. Essa API serve apenas para matar a sessão do token. Pra ele eu preciso passar apenas o Token de sessão conforme exemplo da imagem do postman.

Comment: No Postman ele gera o Header dessa forma:
**Content-Type:application/json
Cookie:authToken=webXPTO123**

Comment: qual o valor da urlApi?

Comment: https://chp.tbe.taleo.net/chp04/ats/api/v1/logout

Comment: Posta um foto da aba Headers(16) do Postman

Comment: Ou melhor ainda no Postman tem uma opção chamada "Code" seleciona a opção JavaScript -> Jquery AJAX, depois compara com sua requisição.

Comment: Obrigado, eu realmente não conhecia essa parte do code do Postman, mas mesmo pegando por lá não está indo. Quando estou debungando, ele chega na linha do cookie e da o seguinte erro: Refused to set unsafe header "cookie":
xhr.setRequestHeader("cookie", "authToken=" + Token);

Comment: @AndersonSouza tinha outro erro escondido, esse aqui:Failed to load https://chp.tbe.taleo.net/chp04/ats/api/v1/logout: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Comment: O header que você pediu:
access-control-allow-headers →x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token
access-control-allow-methods →POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
access-control-allow-origin →*
access-control-max-age →1000
cache-control →no-cache, no-store, max-age=0
connection →Keep-Alive
content-encoding →gzip
content-language →pt-BR
content-type →application/json;charset=UTF-8
date →Fri, 17 Nov 2017 16:17:35 GMT
expires →Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
..Continua

Comment: keep-alive →timeout=5, max=100
pragma →no-cache
server →Apache
transfer-encoding →chunked
vary →Accept-Encoding,User-Agent

Comment: Man  apaga o comentario com o token por segurança

Comment: A relaxa, esse token é de dev e ele muda a cada sessão. Toda vez que eu mando aqui eu apago pelo postman.

Comment: Blz.. esse erro: :Failed to load chp.tbe.taleo.net/chp04/ats/api/v1/logout , é o CORs mas isso é do lado servido. da uma pesquisada como habilitar o Cors ai na api

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse daqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33143776/ajax-request-refused-to-set-unsafe-header Acho que vai responder vocÊ

Answer (score -1):

Tente por o Header desta forma dentro do objeto de configuração do ajax

```html
"headers":{
    "Cookie":"authToken=valorXPTO
}
```

Source: [Documentação JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Nada... Cara estou desde ontem cedo tentando fazer isso funcionar.. Ta Difícil...